# How do I add a simple dialog box to my angular 7 app?

Tags: angular, dialog, angular7

I have an app in angular 7 where I am extracting data from an api, loading the data into a table. The table has a column at the end of it with a button. Clicking on that button calls a function that will simply log the row data to the console. 
Here is my code for that:

My component.ts file:

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { MatTableDataSource } from "@angular/material";
import { Object} from "../object.model";
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
   styleUrls: ["./styles.scss"],
   templateUrl: "./template.html"
})
export class MyRouteData implements OnInit {
   employeeInfoTable : Object[] = [];
   employeeInfoTableDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.employeeInfoTable);
   displayedColumns: string[] = [
     "Name",
     "DateOfBirth",
     "Address",
     "Postcode",
     "Gender",
     "Salary"
     "JobTitle"
     "AdditionalDetails"
  ];

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

   ngOnInit() {
      this.http.get("http://localhost:5000/MyRoute/GetEmployeeInfo")
          .subscribe(response => {
             this.employeeInfoTable = response;
             this.employeeInfoTableDataSource.data = this.employeeInfoTable;
      });
   }

   displayAdditionalDetails(row) {
    console.log("Row sent from link", row);

  }
}

export interface Object{
   id: number;
   Name: string;
   DateOfBirth: Date;
   Address: string;
   Postcode: string;
   Gender: string;
   Salary : number;
   JobTitle : string;
}
```

my template.html file:

```
<mat-card style="height: 98%">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="employeeInfoTableDataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="DateOfBirth">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Date Of Birth </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.DateOfBirth}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Address">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Address </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Address}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Postcode">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Postcode </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Postcode}} </td>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Gender">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Gender </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Gender}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Salary">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Salary </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Salary}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="JobTitle">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Job Title </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.JobTitle}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="AdditionalDetails">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> AdditionalDetails </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">  <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="displayAdditionalDetails(element)">
          <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">description</mat-icon>
        </button></td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</mat-card>
```

What I want to do now is load up a dialog box when the button is selected.

I have added a new html file called dialog-overview-example-dialog.html which contains the following:

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <p>“I find your lack of faith disturbing.” — Darth Vader</p>

</div>
```

and I have added the following to the end of my component.ts file which I got from some tutorial somewhere:

```
@Component({
  selector: "dialog-overview-example-dialog",
  templateUrl: "dialog-overview-example-dialog.html"
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>) {}

  onCloseClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example.html',
})

export class DialogOverviewExample {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '500px' 
    });
  }

}
```

All I need to do now is to figure out how to load the dialog box from the displayAdditionalDetails method. Eventually I will do more with the dialog box but for now just loading the box is good enough.

Thank-you.

Comment: Have you added the dialogComponent & the component where the dialogbox will be called to the "entryComponents" in the app.module.ts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open the dialog:

- Make sure `MatDialog` is injected into your class
- Using the injected dialog, run `dialog.open(component, options)`

  - `component` is what you want to render in the dialog
  - `options` allow to tweak the box, and also pass data into dialog

Example:

```
@Component({
  styleUrls: ["./styles.scss"],
  templateUrl: "./template.html"
})
export class MyRouteData implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  displayAdditionalDetails(row) {
    this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '500px',
      data: row,
    })
  }
}
```

This will open the dialog box for you. Note the `data: row` in the options. This is how you pass data into a dialog.

If you want to use the data in the dialog, you would need to inject MAT_DIALOG_DATA into your dialog component, like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any)
  { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.data); // this is the "row" passed in
  }

  onCloseClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

If you are using AOT compilation, you will also need to add any components rendered as dialogs to your module under `entrycomponents`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [DialogOverviewExampleDialog],
  exports: [
    ...
  ],
})
export class MyModule {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The MyRouteData class already has the following constructor: constructor(private http: HttpClient) {} . I cannot add constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {} to this class as it tells me that multiple constructor implementations are not allowed. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: @Woody just add the extra argument to the constructor. Then both http client and mat dialog handle will get injected into the class.